# Why do modifications to $this inside of a function propagate outside the function?

Tags: php, object

I'm confused about the following output

```
class A{
    public $v = 10;    
    function add($number){
        $this->v +=$number;
    }

}
$a = new A;
echo $a->v . "\n";
$a->add(5);
echo $a->v . "\n";
```

Why does the second line output 15 instead of 10?  I thought changes made to values inside a function do not propagate outside of the function unless you pass by reference.

Comment: I think you need to read up on objects. If you use Google, you can find some good tutorials.

Comment: Insulting the OP achieves nothing.

Comment: It's 1593 now =( .  Anyways I', new to oop (literally started studying it 3 days ago), if you look at all my other posts they're about procedural php, css, sql, etc...

Comment: @user784637 I'd recommend changing your name... I don't think anyone meant to insult OP

Comment: Why on earth was this question closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your remark "changes made to values inside a function do not propagate outside of the function" goes for parameters. Which can be passed 'by value' or 'by reference' for instance:

```
class A{
    public $v = 10;    
    function add($number){
        $number += $this->v;
    }

$b = 5;
$a->add($b);
echo $b; // Will still be 5;
```

In the sample above, $b will become 15 only if it is passed by reference to the function.

In your case, you're not modifying the parameter at all. You're not modifying a local variable either.

You're modifying the property `v` of the object. `$this` is a special variable, that is local to the function, but *references* the object. The actual variable you modify is not `$this`, nor the parameter, but a property of `$a`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  The key point I did not understand is that `$this` _references_ the object

Comment: Yes. Same goes if you would pass an object as a parameter. Objects are always references (or pointers). That means, that you can always change their properties, even if the parameter themselves are not by reference. If an object parameter is passes by reference, that means the function can change the *reference* too, e.g. actually make the parameter point to a different object.

Comment: Yah I just studied that concept.  If you pass an object as an argument, it will be passed by reference (but not if you pass a property of an object as an argument!).  Also thanks for the follow up example.  I now understand that if you did `function add(&$number)` then the value of $b would be incremented by 10

Comment: .. *if* you modify `$number` in the add method, which in your case you don't. :)

Answer (score -2):

But you're passing it by reference. When you use the keyword `$this`, you're already indicating that the class property shall be used.